# C weird modulo operation

Tags: c, modulus

So I've got this thing where I got the following operation:

```
NSInteger articleIndex = self.featuredArticlesCounter % self.featuredArticles.count;
```

In this case self.featuredArticlesCounter is -1 and
self.featuredArticles.count is 10

So it's basically -1 % 10, which should be 9, but the result is 5 instead.

[Google says](https://www.google.bg/search?q=-1+mod+10&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBG503BG503&oq=-1+mod+10&aqs=chrome..69i57.1229j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it's 9.

And if I do `NSInteger articleIndex = -1 % 10;` it gives me -1

I've tried casting the NSUInteger from count to NSInteger and that doesn't work.
I've tried inserting brackets all over the place but that didn't work either.

I've since switched to using `((-1 % 10) + 10) % 10`.

But I'm still wondering what the deal is here.
Any ideas?

**Edit**:

featuredArticlesCounter is a signed int

self.featuredArticles.count is an unsigned int

Comment: @Kevin: That other question does not explain why `-1 % 10` produces 5 in this case. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: What types are `self.featuredArticlesCounter` and `self.featuredArticles.count`? Is “Xcode gives me 5” correct or a typo in the question?

Comment: @Kevin: `unsigned short x = -1; printf("%d\n", x % 10);` produces 5. It may very well be a typo in the question, but the actual fault should be determined, not guessed, before concluding this a duplicate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I realized after I posted that that 2**32 - 1 % 10 is 5.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode nor iOS.

Comment: That's where I observed the issue and I thought it was relevant.

Comment: The edit showing the types of the operands confirms that this question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`featuredArticlesCounter` is evidently an unsigned int. When you thought you set it to -1, you really set it to `2**32 - 1` (~0). [That number mod 10 is 5](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E8-1%29%2510). (Apparently, `2**(8k)-1 % 10` is 5, so it doesn't matter what size unsigned it actually is)

As for why `-1 % 10` is `-1`, I believe in C the mod of negative numbers is implementation-defined, but in this case (as in Java), it is defined such that `x / y + x % y == x`. If you plug negative numbers in, `-1 / 10 + -1 % 10 = -1 -> -1 % 10 = -1`.

Comment: +1 for observation that all lengths of unsigned congruent to 5!

Comment: Unfortunately featuredArticlesCounter is a signed int, the other one is unsigned though, but I don't change its value.

Comment: This is not true for all powers of 2. `(2^33 - 1)%10` is 1. It is true for 2^n iff n is a multiple of 4 > 0, which makes it equivalent to `(16^(n/4) - 1)%10`. The last digit of a power of 16 is always a 6, so after subtracting 1 the last digit is 5.

Comment: @ugohoavgfhw: The comment says `all lengths of unsigned`, and it is intended to apply to modern systems where all integer types are multiples of 8-bit bytes, and the answer says `2**(8k)`, so it also applies only to multiple-of-eight powers of two.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the hardware (or software?) treats the number as an unsigned integer:

1. `-1 == 0xFFFFFFFF` (in two's compliment encoding)
2. `0xFFFFFFFF == 4294967295` (assuming the raw data is an unsigned integer)
3. `4294967295 % 10 == 5` (trivial by observation of last digit)

This would be my best guess.